# Trying to make a functional calculator in java, I can't figure out where I'm going wrong

Tags: java, calculator

I'd like to start off saying that I'm still really new to java, but I promise this is not a troll post.  So I have to make a functional four function calculator for school.  It's really basic but for some reason I can't get it to work properly.  I was given the following as example code, my teacher told us to infer the rest.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator implements ActionListener 
{

  JFrame f1;
  JTextField display;
  JButton b1,b2,addb,equalsb,clearb;
  JPanel p1;
  String value,operation; 
  double secondnum, total;


   public Calculator()
  {
    value = "";
    total = 0.0;
    secondnum = 0.0;

    f1 = new JFrame("Calculator");
    f1.setSize(400,100);
    Container c1 =  f1.getContentPane();

    display = new JTextField(15);
    b1 = new JButton("1");
    b1.addActionListener(this);                  // adds a Listener for Button b1

    b2 = new JButton("2");
    b2.addActionListener(this); 

    addb = new JButton("+");
    addb.addActionListener(this); 

    equalsb = new JButton("=");
    equalsb.addActionListener(this);

    clearb = new JButton("C");
    clearb.addActionListener(this);

    p1 = new JPanel();

    p1.add(display);
    p1.add(b1);
    p1.add(b2);
    p1.add(addb);
    p1.add(equalsb);
    p1.add(clearb);
    c1.add(p1);

    f1.show();

   }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)        
      {                                                    
       if (event.getSource()== b1)      
          value = value + "1";

      if (event.getSource() == b2)     
           value = value + "2";

      if (event.getSource() == clearb)
         {
           total = 0.0; 
           secondnum = 0.0;
           value = "";
         }


      if (event.getSource() == addb)
        {
           total = Double.parseDouble(value);
           operation = "add";
           value = "";
        }

      if (event.getSource() == equalsb)
        {
          secondnum = Double.parseDouble(value);   

          if(operation.equals("add"))
              total = total + secondnum;

          value = ""+ total;            //value becomes what the total is to be diplays  
        }   


   display.setText(value);
    }
  }
```

This works, so from it I created the following.  I'm pretty sure i'm going wrong in the function keys, but I have no clue where I messed up.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator implements ActionListener
{
JFrame f;
Container c; 
JPanel p; 
JTextField display; 
JButton b1, b2, b3, bdiv, b5, b6, b7, bmult, b9, b10, b11, badd, b13, bdecimal, bequals, bsub,        bclear;
String value, operation;
double secondnum, total;
public Calculator()
{
  value = "";
  total = 0.0;
  secondnum = 0.0;
  f = new JFrame("Calculator");
  f.setSize(333,225);
  c = f.getContentPane();
  p = new JPanel();
  display = new JTextField(20);
  b1 = new JButton("7");
  b1.addActionListener(this);
  b2 = new JButton("8");
  b2.addActionListener(this);
  b3 = new JButton("9");
  b3.addActionListener(this);
  bdiv = new JButton("/");
  bdiv.addActionListener(this);
  b5 = new JButton("4");
  b5.addActionListener(this);
  b6 = new JButton("5");
  b6.addActionListener(this);
  b7 = new JButton("6");
  b7.addActionListener(this);
  bmult = new JButton("x");
  bmult.addActionListener(this);
  b9 = new JButton("1");
  b9.addActionListener(this);
  b10 = new JButton("2");
  b10.addActionListener(this);
  b11 = new JButton("3");
  b11.addActionListener(this);
  badd = new JButton("+");
  badd.addActionListener(this);
  b13 = new JButton("0");
  b13.addActionListener(this);
  bdecimal = new JButton(".");
  bdecimal.addActionListener(this);
  bequals = new JButton("=");
  bequals.addActionListener(this);
  bsub = new JButton("-");
  bsub.addActionListener(this);
  bclear = new JButton("C");
  bclear.addActionListener(this);
  p.setBackground(Color.green);
  p.add(display);
  p.add(b1);
  p.add(b2);
  p.add(b3);
  p.add(bdiv);
  p.add(b5);
  p.add(b6);
  p.add(b7);
  p.add(bmult);
  p.add(b9);
  p.add(b10);
  p.add(b11);
  p.add(badd);
  p.add(b13);
  p.add(bdecimal);
  p.add(bequals);
  p.add(bsub);
  p.add(bclear);
  c.add(p);
  f.show();
 }
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) 
    {

        if(event.getSource() == b1)
          {
              value = value + "7";
            }       


        if(event.getSource() == b2)
          {
             value = value + "8";
            }


        if(event.getSource() == b3)
          {
             value = value + "9";
            }  




        if(event.getSource() == b5)
          {
              value = value + "4";
            }


        if(event.getSource() == b6)
          {
              value = value + "5";
            }


        if(event.getSource() == b7)
          {
              value = value + "6";
            }





        if(event.getSource() == b9)
          {
             value = value + "1";
            }


        if(event.getSource() == b10)
          {
              value = value + "2";
            }


        if(event.getSource() == b11)
          {
              value = value + "3";
            }





        if(event.getSource() == b13)
          {
              value = value + "0";
            }


        if(event.getSource() == bdecimal)
          {
             value = value + ".";
            }  

         if(event.getSource() == badd)
          {
             total = Double.parseDouble(value);
              operation = "add";
              value = "";
            }

        if(event.getSource() == bmult)
          {
              total = Double.parseDouble(value);
              operation = "multiply";
              value = "";
            }

       if(event.getSource() == bsub)
          {
               total = Double.parseDouble(value);
              operation = "subtract";
              value = "";
            }

        if(event.getSource() == bdiv)
          {
              total = Double.parseDouble(value);
              operation = "divide";
              value = "";
            }     

       if(event.getSource() == bclear)
          {
              total = 0.0;
              secondnum = 0.0;
              value = "";
            }

       if(event.getSource() == bequals)
       {
           secondnum = Double.parseDouble(value);
         {  
           if(operation.equals("add));
           total = total + secondnum;
        }
         {  
           if(operation.equals("subtract"));
           total = total - secondnum;
        }
           if(operation.equals("divide"));
           total = total / secondnum;
          {  
           if(operation.equals("multiply"));
           total = total * secondnum;
        }
        value = "" + tottal
        }
        display.setText(value);
   }
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated, I realize it's probably just a stupid mistake.

Comment: How exactly is it not working properly?

Comment: You could start by using better variable names (i.e. have `b1` be the 1 button, etc.)

Comment: And by improving your question, giving us more detail on your problem and your confusions.

Comment: Yeah, the variables were really stupid and I haven't gotten around to fixing it.  It's not working because I can try to do 3 * 3 and it will still display 3.0.  I just can't see where it's going wrong.  It does that same thing for all the functions.

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in your code. Also a line like if(operation.equals("multiply")); will do nothing correct will be if(operation.equals("multiply")){  //here goes the code } Heres another error: value = "" + tottal. Here total is spelled with a double t but there is not variable tottal.

Comment: and missing quotes at `if(operation.equals("add));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have strange conditions on the end of the source code:

```
if(operation.equals("multiply"));
       total = total * secondnum;
```

this won't multiply because of semicolon on the end of if
this is better:

```
if(operation.equals("multiply"))
       total = total * secondnum;
```

And I cant understand your block of codes here, if you want to make if do this:

```
if(condition){
     command1;
     command2;
}
```

and not:

```
{
if(condition)
    command1;
    command2;
}
```

Comment: Well, it will multiply, but every time and not just, when the `multiply` button was pressed.

Comment: It works fine when I remove four semicolons and fix two next bugs in this code @Tom

Comment: I just meant the sentence `this won't multiply because of semicolon on the end of if`. It is not quite right.

Comment: You are right, my fault, I wrote it to simplification and for better understanding the problem, not quite/really right, I meant command `total = total * secondnum` will be executed but not depends on if statement, because if executes only next command or block of commands, if there is a semicolon, the semicolon command (no command) will be executed and everything will be done anyway, so it will be added, then substracted, then divided and then multiplied, so you will got the same number..., is it right @Tom?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, if `;` will be interpreted as a command or as a termination for the `if` block/statement. But that doesn't matter :D.

Comment: I am not sure too, but this will do the same xD @Tom